what is causing the memory leaks?
i'm making a game called square eater where i have a square which the user can move around by using the keyboard arrows and quit the game by pressing 'q'. now i made sure that i didn't allocate any resource manually so memory should be cleaned automatically. I've attached the output of valgrind at the end. here is my code
#ifdef __APPLE__
#include<GLUT/glut.h>
#else
#include<GL/glut.h>
#endif
#include<GL/freeglut.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<string>
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include <cstdlib>
#include<time.h>
#include<array>
typedef struct point
{
   float x;
   float y;
}point;
typedef struct color
{
   float r;
   float g;
   float b;
}color;


int number_of_segments = 200;

float logX = 200;
float logY = 200;

int PhyWidth = 1000;
int PhyHeight = 1000;

int windowPosX = 500;
int windowPosY = 500;

float centerX = logX / 2;
float centerY = logY / 2;
int alphaX = 0;
int alphaY = 0;


typedef unsigned char u8;

class square
{
    private:

        std::array<point, 4> pts;
        float width;
        float height;
        bool  filled;
        float max_x;
        float min_x;
        float max_y;
        float min_y;
        int id;
        bool eaten = false;
        color colour = {1.0, 1.0, 1.0};
        bool main;
    public:
        square(point pt, int width, int height, bool filled, bool main)
        {
            this->width = width;
            this->height = height;
            this->filled = filled;
            this->main = main;
            float half_width = width/2;
            float half_height = height/2;
            min_x = pt.x - half_width;
            max_x = pt.x + half_width;
            min_y = pt.y - half_height;
            max_y = pt.y + half_height;
            this->pts[0] = {min_x, min_y};
            this->pts[1] = {max_x, min_y};
            this->pts[2] = {max_x, max_y};
            this->pts[3] = {min_x, max_y};
        }
        square(point pt, int width, int height, bool main, color colour, int id)
        {
            this->id = id;
            this->width = width;
            this->height = height;
            this->main = main;
            this->colour = colour;
            float half_width = width/2;
            float half_height = height/2;
            min_x = pt.x - half_width;
            max_x = pt.x + half_width;
            min_y = pt.y - half_height;
            max_y = pt.y + half_height;
            this->pts[0] = {min_x, min_y};
            this->pts[1] = {max_x, min_y};
            this->pts[2] = {max_x, max_y};
            this->pts[3] = {min_x, max_y};
        }

        std::array<point, 4> get_pts()
        {
            return this->pts;
        }
        void set_eaten()
        {
            this->eaten = true;
        }
        bool get_eaten()
        {
            return eaten;
        }
        void draw()
        {
            int alphaX_copy = 0;
            int alphaY_copy = 0;
            if(main)
            {
                alphaX_copy = alphaX;
                alphaY_copy = alphaY;
            }
            glColor4f(colour.r, colour.g, colour.b, 1);
            glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
                glVertex2f(this->pts[0].x + alphaX_copy, this->pts[0].y + alphaY_copy);
                glVertex2f(this->pts[1].x + alphaX_copy, this->pts[1].y + alphaY_copy);
                glVertex2f(this->pts[2].x + alphaX_copy, this->pts[2].y + alphaY_copy);
                glVertex2f(this->pts[3].x + alphaX_copy, this->pts[3].y + alphaY_copy);
            glEnd();
        }
        static bool intersected_squares(square& big_square, square& small_square)
        {
            for (size_t i = 0; i < 4; i++)
            {
                if( small_square.pts[i].x > (big_square.min_x + alphaX) && small_square.pts[i].x < (big_square.max_x + alphaX))
                {
                    // means in the range of x
                    if(small_square.pts[i].y > (big_square.min_y + alphaY) && small_square.pts[i].y < (big_square.max_y + alphaY))
                    {
                        // std::cout<<"Bingo!";
                        return true;
                    }

                }
            }
            return false;
        }
};


std::string score = "0";

square big_square({centerX,centerY}, 20, 20, true, {1.0, 0, 0}, 1);
std::vector<square> little_squares;

void display(void);
void init(void);
void keyboard(u8 key, int x, int y);
void special_keyboard(int key, int x, int y);


void draw_text(std::string str, point pt);


int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    float r,g,b;
    int x,y;
    srand(time(0));
    for (size_t i = 0; i < 9; i++)
    {
        r = std::rand() % 256;
        g = std::rand() % 256;
        b = std::rand() % 256;
        r /= 255.0;
        g /= 255.0;
        b /= 255.0;
        x = std::rand() % 80;
        y = std::rand() % 80;
        point p = {x,y};
        color colour = {r,g,b};
        little_squares.emplace_back(p, 6, 6, false, colour, i+2);

    }


    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGB);
    glutSetOption(GLUT_ACTION_ON_WINDOW_CLOSE,GLUT_ACTION_CONTINUE_EXECUTION);
    glutInitWindowSize(PhyWidth, PhyHeight);
    glutInitWindowPosition(windowPosX,windowPosY);
    int window = glutCreateWindow("Shehab");
    init();
    glutDisplayFunc(display);
    glutKeyboardFunc(keyboard);
    glutSpecialFunc(special_keyboard);
    glutMainLoop();
    std::cout<<"out\n";
    glutExit();

    return 0;
}

void display(void)
{

    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    big_square.draw();
    for(int i = 0; i < little_squares.size(); i++)
    {
        if(little_squares[i].get_eaten())
        {
            continue;
        }
        else if(square::intersected_squares(big_square, little_squares[i]))
        {
            little_squares[i].set_eaten();
            score[0]++;
            continue;
        }
        little_squares[i].draw();
    }
    draw_text("score is "+  score, {10 ,190});
    glutSwapBuffers();
    glFlush();
}

void init(void)
{

    glClearColor(0.0, 0, 1.0, 1);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    gluOrtho2D(0, logX, 0, logY);
}



void draw_text(std::string str, point pt)
{
   glRasterPos2d(pt.x, pt.y);
   for (int i=0;i<str.size();i++)
    glutBitmapCharacter(GLUT_BITMAP_HELVETICA_18,str[i]);
}


void special_keyboard(int key, int x, int y)
{
    if(key == GLUT_KEY_UP)
    {
        alphaY += 5;
    }
    else if(key == GLUT_KEY_DOWN)
    {
        alphaY -= 5;
    }
    else if(key == GLUT_KEY_RIGHT)
    {
        alphaX += 5;
    }
    else if(key == GLUT_KEY_LEFT)
    {
        alphaX -= 5;
    }

    glutPostRedisplay();
}

void keyboard(u8 key, int x, int y)
{
    if(key == 'q')
    {
        glutLeaveMainLoop();
    }
}


here is the output of valgrind
==27343== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==27343== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==27343== Using Valgrind-3.18.1 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==27343== Command: ./snake
==27343== 
==27343== Warning: noted but unhandled ioctl 0x644f with no size/direction hints.
==27343==    This could cause spurious value errors to appear.
==27343==    See README_MISSING_SYSCALL_OR_IOCTL for guidance on writing a proper wrapper.
out
==27343== 
==27343== HEAP SUMMARY:
==27343==     in use at exit: 58,665 bytes in 522 blocks
==27343==   total heap usage: 15,762 allocs, 15,240 frees, 871,820,047 bytes allocated
==27343== 
==27343== 0 bytes in 2 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 1 of 128
==27343==    at 0x4848899: malloc (in /usr/libexec/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==27343==    by 0x4005A22: malloc (rtld-malloc.h:56)
==27343==    by 0x4005A22: _dl_find_object_update (dl-find_object.c:791)
==27343==    by 0x400ECCF: dl_open_worker_begin (dl-open.c:735)
==27343==    by 0x4D67A97: _dl_catch_exception (dl-error-skeleton.c:208)
==27343==    by 0x400DF99: dl_open_worker (dl-open.c:782)
==27343==    by 0x4D67A97: _dl_catch_exception (dl-error-skeleton.c:208)
==27343==    by 0x400E34D: _dl_open (dl-open.c:883)
==27343==    by 0x4C8363B: dlopen_doit (dlopen.c:56)
==27343==    by 0x4D67A97: _dl_catch_exception (dl-error-skeleton.c:208)
==27343==    by 0x4D67B62: _dl_catch_error (dl-error-skeleton.c:227)
==27343==    by 0x4C8312D: _dlerror_run (dlerror.c:138)
==27343==    by 0x4C836C7: dlopen_implementation (dlopen.c:71)
==27343==    by 0x4C836C7: dlopen@@GLIBC_2.34 (dlopen.c:81)
==27343== 
==27343== 8 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 10 of 128
==27343==    at 0x48487A9: malloc (in /usr/libexec/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==27343==    by 0xBD63379: ???
==27343==    by 0xBD4D56F: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdrm.so.2.4.0)
==27343==    by 0xBD505B1: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdrm.so.2.4.0)
==27343==    by 0xBD50913: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdrm.so.2.4.0)
==27343==    by 0x621481E: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnvidia-glcore.so.550.67)
==27343==    by 0x6227222: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnvidia-glcore.so.550.67)
==27343==    by 0x6227817: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnvidia-glcore.so.550.67)
==27343==    by 0x670AFDC: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnvidia-glcore.so.550.67)
==27343==    by 0x61B24B3: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnvidia-glcore.so.550.67)
==27343==    by 0x61BA4FA: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnvidia-glcore.so.550.67)
==27343==    by 0x5646143: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLX_nvidia.so.550.67)
==27343== 
==27343== 29 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 24 of 128
==27343==    at 0x4848899: malloc (in /usr/libexec/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==27343==    by 0xBD6A8F3: ???
==27343==    by 0xBD50CE7: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdrm.so.2.4.0)
==27343==    by 0x621481E: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnvidia-glcore.so.550.67)
==27343==    by 0x6227222: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnvidia-glcore.so.550.67)
==27343==    by 0x6227817: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnvidia-glcore.so.550.67)
==27343==    by 0x670AFDC: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnvidia-glcore.so.550.67)
==27343==    by 0x61B24B3: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnvidia-glcore.so.550.67)
==27343==    by 0x61BA4FA: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnvidia-glcore.so.550.67)
==27343==    by 0x5646143: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLX_nvidia.so.550.67)
==27343==    by 0x5646287: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLX_nvidia.so.550.67)
==27343==    by 0x5670F07: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLX_nvidia.so.550.67)
==27343== 
==27343== 29 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 25 of 128
==27343==    at 0x4848899: malloc (in /usr/libexec/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==27343==    by 0xBD6A8F3: ???
==27343==    by 0xBD50CAA: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdrm.so.2.4.0)
==27343==    by 0x621481E: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnvidia-glcore.so.550.67)
==27343==    by 0x6227222: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnvidia-glcore.so.550.67)
==27343==    by 0x6227817: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnvidia-glcore.so.550.67)
==27343==    by 0x670AFDC: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnvidia-glcore.so.550.67)
==27343==    by 0x61B24B3: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnvidia-glcore.so.550.67)
==27343==    by 0x61BA4FA: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnvidia-glcore.so.550.67)
==27343==    by 0x5646143: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLX_nvidia.so.550.67)
==27343==    by 0x5646287: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLX_nvidia.so.550.67)
==27343==    by 0x5670F07: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLX_nvidia.so.550.67)
==27343== 
==27343== 38 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 29 of 128
==27343==    at 0x4848899: malloc (in /usr/libexec/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==27343==    by 0xBD6A8F3: ???
==27343==    by 0xBD50AD9: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdrm.so.2.4.0)
==27343==    by 0x621481E: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnvidia-glcore.so.550.67)
==27343==    by 0x6227222: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnvidia-glcore.so.550.67)
==27343==    by 0x6227817: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnvidia-glcore.so.550.67)
==27343==    by 0x670AFDC: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnvidia-glcore.so.550.67)
==27343==    by 0x61B24B3: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnvidia-glcore.so.550.67)
==27343==    by 0x61BA4FA: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnvidia-glcore.so.550.67)
==27343==    by 0x5646143: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLX_nvidia.so.550.67)
==27343==    by 0x5646287: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLX_nvidia.so.550.67)
==27343==    by 0x5670F07: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLX_nvidia.so.550.67)
==27343== 
==27343== 40 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 41 of 128
==27343==    at 0x484DA83: calloc (in /usr/libexec/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==27343==    by 0xBD6AAD7: ???
==27343==    by 0xBD71706: ???
==27343==    by 0xBD7176F: ???
==27343==    by 0xBD717DC: ???
==27343==    by 0xBD488F8: drmGetContextTag (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdrm.so.2.4.0)
==27343==    by 0xBD4F46B: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdrm.so.2.4.0)
==27343==    by 0xBD509D6: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdrm.so.2.4.0)
==27343==    by 0x621481E: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnvidia-glcore.so.550.67)
==27343==    by 0x6227222: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnvidia-glcore.so.550.67)
==27343==    by 0x6227817: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnvidia-glcore.so.550.67)
==27343==    by 0x670AFDC: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnvidia-glcore.so.550.67)
==27343== 
==27343== 96 (24 direct, 72 indirect) bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 81 of 128
==27343==    at 0x4848899: malloc (in /usr/libexec/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==27343==    by 0xBD71F3D: ???
==27343==    by 0xBD5DE35: ???
==27343==    by 0xBD62B0E: ???
==27343==    by 0xBD503D2: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdrm.so.2.4.0)
==27343==    by 0xBD5065B: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdrm.so.2.4.0)
==27343==    by 0xBD50913: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdrm.so.2.4.0)
==27343==    by 0x621481E: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnvidia-glcore.so.550.67)
==27343==    by 0x6227222: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnvidia-glcore.so.550.67)
==27343==    by 0x6227817: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnvidia-glcore.so.550.67)
==27343==    by 0x670AFDC: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnvidia-glcore.so.550.67)
==27343==    by 0x61B24B3: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnvidia-glcore.so.550.67)
==27343== 
==27343== 152 (112 direct, 40 indirect) bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 84 of 128
==27343==    at 0x484DA83: calloc (in /usr/libexec/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==27343==    by 0xBD69E2F: ???
==27343==    by 0xBD4F66F: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdrm.so.2.4.0)
==27343==    by 0xBD509D6: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdrm.so.2.4.0)
==27343==    by 0x621481E: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnvidia-glcore.so.550.67)
==27343==    by 0x6227222: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnvidia-glcore.so.550.67)
==27343==    by 0x6227817: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnvidia-glcore.so.550.67)
==27343==    by 0x670AFDC: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnvidia-glcore.so.550.67)
==27343==    by 0x61B24B3: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnvidia-glcore.so.550.67)
==27343==    by 0x61BA4FA: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnvidia-glcore.so.550.67)
==27343==    by 0x5646143: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLX_nvidia.so.550.67)
==27343==    by 0x5646287: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLX_nvidia.so.550.67)
==27343== 
==27343== 520 bytes in 13 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 111 of 128
==27343==    at 0x4848899: malloc (in /usr/libexec/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==27343==    by 0xBD6E045: ???
==27343==    by 0xBD626FC: ???
==27343==    by 0xBD50804: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdrm.so.2.4.0)
==27343==    by 0x621481E: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnvidia-glcore.so.550.67)
==27343==    by 0x6227222: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnvidia-glcore.so.550.67)
==27343==    by 0x6227817: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnvidia-glcore.so.550.67)
==27343==    by 0x670AFDC: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnvidia-glcore.so.550.67)
==27343==    by 0x61B24B3: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnvidia-glcore.so.550.67)
==27343==    by 0x61BA4FA: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnvidia-glcore.so.550.67)
==27343==    by 0x5646143: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLX_nvidia.so.550.67)
==27343==    by 0x5646287: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLX_nvidia.so.550.67)
==27343== 
==27343== 567 (184 direct, 383 indirect) bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 112 of 128
==27343==    at 0x484DA83: calloc (in /usr/libexec/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==27343==    by 0xBD5D16F: ???
==27343==    by 0xBD5E4DF: ???
==27343==    by 0xBD4FFC9: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdrm.so.2.4.0)
==27343==    by 0xBD503A0: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdrm.so.2.4.0)
==27343==    by 0xBD5065B: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdrm.so.2.4.0)
==27343==    by 0xBD50913: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdrm.so.2.4.0)
==27343==    by 0x621481E: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnvidia-glcore.so.550.67)
==27343==    by 0x6227222: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnvidia-glcore.so.550.67)
==27343==    by 0x6227817: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnvidia-glcore.so.550.67)
==27343==    by 0x670AFDC: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnvidia-glcore.so.550.67)
==27343==    by 0x61B24B3: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnvidia-glcore.so.550.67)
==27343== 
==27343== 10,680 (48 direct, 10,632 indirect) bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 128 of 128
==27343==    at 0x484DA83: calloc (in /usr/libexec/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==27343==    by 0xBD4D9C9: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdrm.so.2.4.0)
==27343==    by 0xBD4F4CF: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdrm.so.2.4.0)
==27343==    by 0xBD509D6: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdrm.so.2.4.0)
==27343==    by 0x621481E: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnvidia-glcore.so.550.67)
==27343==    by 0x6227222: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnvidia-glcore.so.550.67)
==27343==    by 0x6227817: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnvidia-glcore.so.550.67)
==27343==    by 0x670AFDC: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnvidia-glcore.so.550.67)
==27343==    by 0x61B24B3: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnvidia-glcore.so.550.67)
==27343==    by 0x61BA4FA: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnvidia-glcore.so.550.67)
==27343==    by 0x5646143: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLX_nvidia.so.550.67)
==27343==    by 0x5646287: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLX_nvidia.so.550.67)
==27343== 
==27343== LEAK SUMMARY:
==27343==    definitely lost: 1,032 bytes in 24 blocks
==27343==    indirectly lost: 11,127 bytes in 59 blocks
==27343==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==27343==    still reachable: 46,506 bytes in 439 blocks
==27343==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==27343== Reachable blocks (those to which a pointer was found) are not shown.
==27343== To see them, rerun with: --leak-check=full --show-leak-kinds=all
==27343== 
==27343== For lists of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -s
==27343== ERROR SUMMARY: 11 errors from 11 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)


i tried to see if how i'm terminating the program would make a different result. but it didn't.
I tried using exit(0) when 'q' is pressed, and by pressing the close button in the window itself.

Take quite a few steps back, and start over with an empty main function. Build with extra warnings enabled and treated as errors. Once it builds cleanly, test the program in all possible ways. Once all tests passes, add a very small bit of code, perhaps even just one or two lines. Build and test as before. If you have a problem it will become much easier to isolate into a [mre] and to debug it.

There is a leak in memory allocated by the library and valgrind doesn't have access to debugging symbols to point to something specific. I don't know glut, but on the first glance glutCreateWindow has corresponding function glutDestroyWindow which presumably should be called to release allocated resources. Maybe other things need to be deallocated too.

now i made sure that i didn't allocate any resource manually so memory should be cleaned automatically. -- But did you make sure you are usng the API correctly (glut) so that you are calling their allocation and deallocation functions properly?

And some review of the code you show: There's no need for typedef for structures. You use too many global variables. Why don't you use either two points (e.g. upper left and lower right), or one point and a width/height pair for the square? Or since it's a square just one point and one size? Try to use standard types, like std::uint8_t instead of u8. And generally, your code have a C-feel to it, not much C++.

@Yksisarvinen Oh I'm sorry i forgot to say that I've tried using the glutDestroyWindow after the exiting glut main loop but it gave me an error " freeglut  ERROR:  Function  called without first calling 'glutInit'. "

@PaulMcKenzie honestly no, I'm using the same code i've been taught in my class and they never talked about memory leaks there. And i thought it might be a good idea to try going OO and try to learn C++ in the process.

@Someprogrammerdude  thanks for your input, i'll try to do MRE. Most of the time i code in C so yeah that's why it is more of C-ish.

In this case it appears that the asker did not knowingly touch raw pointers to dynamic allocations. They were all hidden behind opaque handles. What they really needed to spend their time on resolving was freeglut ERROR: Function  called without first calling 'glutInit'. because calling glutDestroyWindow was a step in the right direction.

@Red.Wave But in my case here i'm not dealing with raw pointers (didn't create new ones by myself in my code I mean). I've just tested other simpler GLUT programs and they were leaking as well, so it is a problem of how i'm using GLUT, I think that i should look for any guide on how use it properly.

@user4581301 i've inserted " glutInit(&argc, argv) " before the " glutDestroyWindow " and the error disappeared but the output of valgrind is the same.

To get an idea of what @Red.Wave means, read the C++ core guidelines. That's how C++ should be used, GLUT only has a "C" api so make an adapter layer.

That glutinit call should be up near the start of the program to initialize glut BEFORE you start using glut rather than after. Not sure what happens if you call it at the end of the program rather than the beginning. And in the given code example, I do see a call to it. So why did glutDestroyWindow think it had not been called. This you need to investigate.

@user4581301 yeah that what buzzes me right now. I have a theory that exiting the GlutMainLoop already destroys the window, but the thing is I have no idea how to debug this kind of programs (I used to debug by GDB).

When you believe the problem cannot be in your code, you could do a quick gut check of your code. Instead of "a game called square eater", try a game called "quit". As in, there is nothing to do but "quit the game by pressing 'q'". It's not much fun to play, but it is a lot more fun to debug. ;)

@ShehabBadawy "I've tried using the glutDestroyWindow after the exiting glut main loop" -- Have you tried calling it before (or instead of) exiting the main loop? When 'q' is pressed, destroy the window, but let the loop run (and maybe end itself when it detects that there are no more windows). I don't know about GLUT, but some other frameworks operate that way.

@JaMiT yeah I tried the quit game and it still has same memory leaks. I've just tried your suggestion of using glutDestroyWindow when pressing 'q' and it doesn't output " freeglut ERROR: Function   " but the memory leaks are the same.

@ShehabBadawy "I tried the quit game and it still has same memory leaks." -- Good, that means you can [edit] your question and simplify the code.
